# mapstruct do not allow create object with all nullable fields

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

How to involve creation of object using mapstruct with nullable fields. If all fields in created object will be null - set parent object as null

```
@Mapping(source = "street1", target = "street")
@Mapping(source = "city1", target = "city")
Address2 toNewAddress(Address1 address);
```

I want to get Address2 null when street and city are null, but now I have:

Address2 object with street and city null;

Answer (score 0):

perhaps not the most satisfying answer. But I think the only way to do it, is to wrap the mapping method like this:

```java
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    default Address2 wrapToNewAddress(Address1 s) {
        return s.getCity1() == null && s.getStreet1() == null ? null : toNewAddress( s );
    }

    @Mapping(source = "street1", target = "street")
    @Mapping(source = "city1", target = "city")
    Address2 toNewAddress(Address1 address);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've already solved it using Decorator

Comment: could you mark the answer as correct for other users to find it..?